# Android Vector fillColor not working

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

I want to fill this Vector in Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="118.05486dp"
android:height="315.81244dp"
android:viewportWidth="118.05486"
android:viewportHeight="315.81244">

  <group
    android:translateX="59.027433"
    android:translateY="-747.84646">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M 9.400849,1063.1651 58.533589,752.95315 M -9.400849,1063.1651
        -58.533589,752.95315 m 117.067178,0 a 374.17323,374.17323 0 0 0 -117.067178,0 M
        9.400849,1063.1651 a 60.094488,60.094488 0 0 0 -18.801698,0" />
  </group>
</vector>
```

The Vector looks like this:
[Vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfsNM.png)
(The top- and bottom-side is rounded)
The android:fillColor attribute is not working.
Or is this only doable with a bitmap?

edit:
To clarify my problem, here another picture:
[Vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KzSI.png)
The left side vector uses android:fillColor, which fills only a little bit on the top. The right side uses android:tint, which only colors the lines.
What I want is to fill the whole vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the path describing the shape is a bit confusing, possibly due to the original graphics software used, the order things were drawn or some conversion process.

`VectorDrawable` pathData is in the same format as SVG, [detailed information about pathData can be found here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

If I break the `pathData` into separate lines it will look a bit clearer (and is still totally valid, things will still run fine and it's easier to read)

```
android:pathData="M 9.400849,1063.1651 58.533589,752.95315 
                  M -9.400849,1063.1651 -58.533589,752.95315 
                  m 117.067178,0 
                  a 374.17323,374.17323 0 0 0 -117.067178,0 
                  M 9.400849,1063.1651 
                  a 60.094488,60.094488 0 0 0 -18.801698,0"
```

The lines beginning 'M' or 'm' are `moveto` commands; moving the pen to a different place on the screen.
The lines beginning 'a' are eliptical arcs, the curved lines.

So from this a couple of things stand out. There are no straight lines explicitly drawn in this path (straight line commands use 'L' or 'l').

There are a number of `moveto` commands before any command to start drawing(basically saying "start here"..."actually no over here"..."no here!").

Ideally what we want is a shape which is a bit clearer and more deliberate, that starts at one point and draws all the way around until it gets to the end; the area we want to fill should be clearly defined.

```
android:pathData="M 58.533589,752.95315
                  a 374.17323,374.17323 0 0 0 -117.067178,0
                  L -9.400849,1063.1651
                  a -60.094488,60.094488 0 0 0 18.801698,0
                  L 58.533589,752.95315"
```

Comparing the two, you'll see mostly the same numbers. The same coordinates cleaned up and rearranged. Now describing moving to a starting point, then drawing an arc, a line, the other arc, then the other line. Using `fillColor` should now be fine, the shape is just a simple, defined outline.

Comment: Thanks alot, now I understand svg a bit more. I have used Inkscape, maybe I should look around for another programm.

Comment: @Wuzzzel Inkscape's very popular, I'm sure it's fine! Don't really know why this particular image ended up this way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue like my changes for vector are not reflecting in device, it is reflecting in preview but on actual device the changes are not getting reflected. So, I thought fill color is not working but ***the actual issue is the same name vector files in two different modules***.

Android will only pick one of the files if two files are named the same. So, be cautious before naming a file.

Answer (score -5):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        **android:fillColor="#FF000000"**
        android:pathData="M6,18c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h1v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L11,19h2v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L16,19h1c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1L18,8L6,8v10zM3.5,8C2.67,8 2,8.67 2,9.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S5,17.33 5,16.5v-7C5,8.67 4.33,8 3.5,8zM20.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5v-7c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5zM15.53,2.16l1.3,-1.3c0.2,-0.2 0.2,-0.51 0,-0.71 -0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0l-1.48,1.48C13.85,1.23 12.95,1 12,1c-0.96,0 -1.86,0.23 -2.66,0.63L7.85,0.15c-0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0 -0.2,0.2 -0.2,0.51 0,0.71l1.31,1.31C6.97,3.26 6,5.01 6,7h12c0,-1.99 -0.97,-3.75 -2.47,-4.84zM10,5L9,5L9,4h1v1zM15,5h-1L14,4h1v1z"/>
</vector>
```

Change the fillcolor

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The android:tint attribute only sets the color of the line (like strokeColor).I know it should normally fill it.  I think there is something wrong with the pathData?

Comment: change the fill color value

Comment: can u share the screenshot what exactly u need

Answer (score -5):

For you want rounded corners.. create xml file in drawable folder

<

```
shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/color_dark_blue" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

change the radius dependent upon your shape

Comment: One answer is enough. Merge them.