How to make android studio dysplay correct color of vector icons intead of purple?
I need help with the code in my app, I created a vector of an add button and coded it with the color orange:
add_circle.xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF9900"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>
</vector>

but when I try to apply on the screen it turns purple, and I don't know how to fix it
<Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_circle"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

Visual reference of the button on the XML file and on the running app
can anyone assist me with this problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685084/changing-fill-color-of-vector-resource-doesnt-work or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521532/android-vector-fillcolor-not-working
should help

@JustSightseeing sorry i tried both those metods, also all other coloring and tint metods my friends recomended and still won't work

Use this:
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_test_tint"
        app:iconSize="60dp"
        app:iconTint="@null" />


Looks like your design's primary color is yellow, why not make it be your theme's primary color?
